# How to include Apache POI copyright?

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-poi

I am creating an Android-App for the company I am working in. It's something that we don't want to sell. We are using it in order to improve our daily work. However, I am using Apache POI to read and write Excel-files.

My question is, am I allowed to use Apache POI for commercial reasons? And how do I have to mark my source code?

I searched for a while but did not find anything useful and I was not able to find a e-mail to contact.

Would be nice if sb. kann help me!

Comment: Did you read the license?  https://poi.apache.org/legal.html and https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about copyright terms.